# Why doesn't $p_{\scriptstyle X}$ give me a small cap X subscript?

Tags: math-mode

The subject line is the question. `$p_X$`
is the label I am using for a probability mass function - common - but I'd like the `X` to be a little smaller than the `p`. I thought the `\scriptstyle` would do it but it doesn't. What am I missing?

(BTW, shouldn't $ - $ display here in math mode?)

Comment: subscripts are already scriptstyle so specfying it does nothing.  mathjax is not enabled here, use an image to show tex output

Comment: The `X` in the expression`$p_X$` is already in `\scriptstyle`, so adding that has no effect. You could use `$p_{\scriptscriptstyle X}$` to make the `X` smaller if you want.

Comment: Got it and Got it. Thanks to you both. I'm out of your hair.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to up tick the comments last night. Just did now -- sorry to you both for being tardy.